# Error: Failed to execute child process "kfmclient" (No such file or directory)

Tags: lubuntu, pcmanfm

I'm using PCManFM and recovered my Lubuntu 14.04.3 Trusty Tahr recently. After the recovery, when I press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> key, I get the error message

```
Failed to execute child process "kfmclient" (No such file or directory)
```

I can open folders via Accessories > PCManFM fine and also by clicking on folders. Just that shortcut approach gives this message. I've searched on Google, Ask Ubuntu and other forums but nothing relevant is coming up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After digging into [shortcuts in Lubuntu](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1422861), I found the solution.

First, I had to edit `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml`

Replace the binding for `W-e` pointing to kfmclient (found it by searching for kfmclient), final result is `<command>pcmanfm</command>`.

Next, I had to run `openbox --reconfigure` in the terminal.

Now the shortcut works as expected.